# TFS Api throws ItemNotFoundException when trying to delete a file if the parent folder has a pending delete

Tags: c#, tfs

If I try and delete a file in TFS, it fails if any of the files parent folders has a pending delete.

Is there a nice way to check if the file can be safely deleted?

VersionControlServer.ServerItemExists returns true, and Workspace.GetPendingChanges returns nothing for the item, yet a call to PendDelete results in NonFatalError firing with an ItemNotFoundException.

I know I could ignore the 'non fatal error', but it really feels like I'm missing something and there should be a cleaner way to do this.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue. The GetPendingChagnes returns delete pending changes and doesn't throw exception when call PendDelete method. Is the workspace in current machine? What's the detail of your code?

Comment: Was about to post a code snippet when I realized that the solution may be as simple as passing 'updateDisk:false' to the PendDelete method. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: I didn't specify updateDisk parameter. What's the result if you specify updateDisk to false? If it solves your issue, you can post an answer and accept it as answer.

Comment: But the return result is 0 when call PendDelete method. What's the version of your library and TFS? Try to use this package instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/

Comment: Sorry, will reply with some more info soon. I needed this fixed quickly, so for now I've just made sure everything gets deleted in the right order (files before folders) and that works fine. Will go back and work out a proper solution when I get the time.